# 'variable' may be used uninitialized in this function, have a working workaround but don't understand why

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

***I have searched and found a lot of similar questions (with undoubtly good answers) but I haven't found one that I understand completely. I have found a solution that does work and I am really just trying to understand what I do wrong in the first example...***

I wrote a function that calculates pitch/roll from raw accelerometer values with declaration:

```
uint8_t calcPitchRoll (imu_t * imu, float * pitch, float * roll);
```

The calling function looks like (line numbers for reference):

```
518 float * pRollValue, * pPitchValue; // prepare pointers to floats to store results
519 *pRollValue = 0; // initialize variables
520 *pPitchValue = 0; // initialize variables
521 calcPitchRoll (imu, pPitchValue, pRollValue);
```

However, that results in the compiler warnings:

```
main.c:519:25: warning: 'pRollValue' may be used uninitialized in this function
main.c:521:26: warning: 'pPitchValue' may be used uninitialized in this function
```

The following however does work:

```
float PitchValue, RollValue = 0;
float * pRollValue = &RollValue;
float * pPitchValue = &PitchValue;
calcPitchRoll (imu, pPitchValue, pRollValue);
```

To me, both examples seem to have the same "state" when calling the calcPitchRoll function, but the compiler disagrees.

What I (think I) understood is that `*pRollValue = 0` writes that value to the variable, so I'd think at that point the variable has space allocated ànd a value. Is that an incorrect understanding?

Comment: In the first one you dereferencing an unitialized pointer which can point to bascially any random memory address  (or its 0 if made in the global scope) which is undefined behaviour. (`*pRollValue = 0;`) while in the second your pointers points to actual existing operands locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a huge difference in your two code examples.

Look at this:

```
518 float * pRollValue, * pPitchValue;  // Here pRollValue is uninitialized
519 *pRollValue = 0;                    // Here you dereference pRollValue (due to the *)
    ^        
    |                           // So you dereference an uninitialized pointer
    |
    Dereference of uninitialized pointer
```

Here

```
float PitchValue, RollValue = 0;
float * pRollValue = &RollValue;  // You define a pointer and at the
                                  // same time you initializes it to
                                  // point to a float
```

So the two code parts are completely different.

So you need to understand the difference between a **pointer to an object of type T** and a **object of type T**.

Code like

```
float * pF;
```

will give you memory for holding **a pointer to float** but there is no place to store the float itself. You need to assign a value to the pointer so that it points to a float.

So you need something like:

```
float * pF;
float myFloatVariable;
pF = &myFloatVariable;  // Now pF points to myFloatVariable

*pF = 42;               // These two statements both sets
myFloatVariable = 42;   // the variable myFloatVariable to 42
```

An alternative approach is dynamic allocation - like:

```
float * pF = malloc(sizeof *pF);
assert(pF != NULL);

*pF = 42;               // This sets the dynamic allocated float to 42
```

Comment: So my understanding that *pRollValue is a way to "set the value of the variable that this pointer points to" is incorrect? And at line 518 (initial example) I have created a memory place for a pointer (so allocated memory for the pointer), but not set a value (so there's space for a pointer, but there's no real pointer yet). Is that correct?

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD Sounds like you got it

Comment: Or, more correct, *pRollValue can be used to set the value that the pointer points to, but the way I did this, the pointer doesn't point to anything yet? (or worse, it is a random memory address that it points to)

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD Sounds correct - see update

Comment: OK, that makes perfect sense now. Thank you!